# Wd green 1tb hdd won't detect after partitioning gpt table

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I've WD green 1 tb internal hdd.
I've partition it gpt table and ext4.

It wasn't done successfully still it was showing unallocated space so when I reboot the next time hdd won't detect.

I tried in other sata ports and change capables but it doesn't work.

Also not getting ticking noise from hdd.

Is the hdd dead?

Or how can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like it's dead indeed. Better now during partitioning than with your precious data on it!

Comment: It was new hdd and when I make partitioning it takes a lot time for creating table and it failed to create table and was showing unallocated space so when I rebooted it doesn't detect

Comment: And I can get clicking sound within few minutes. I don't know why it failed to create table succefully.

Comment: If it's new, get it replaced. Don't bother with fixing malfunctioning new hardware, get rid of it now to avoid surprises later.

Comment: Sure thanks I've reported them for replacement. Thank you so much for time and efforts